# Create a new window in another program

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm making a .dll plug-in for a program which will get some informations from the running program. Now i have to do a little graphical part: a window(same style of the program windows and popups) with a couple of buttons with specific functions where i present a list with some informations i calculate from the program.

I'm working with MFC so i think i should use the classes like CRect, CBrush,CPen,etc but that seems like it's too much work with a big learning curve. 
I spent all day searching for a good solution and i'm lost. What do you think is the best solution for making a child window alike the program that window is in?

Thank you

Comment: *Create a new window in another program* Unless you want to inject code into a remote process, you can simply create a window with a cross-process parent. This is less fraught than injecting code, but still fraught.

Comment: Cross-process parent-> How do you recommend doing this?
When you say "fraught" you are refering to the difficulty?

Comment: Find the window of another process and then create yourself as a child of it.

Comment: Ok. Which class do you recommend me using? And also,do you know any good website so that a noob at this specific subject is able to start? Thank you for the help mate

Answer (score 1):

Make your window in the visual dialog editor, with the buttons etc. placed on it from the toolbar. Then use "Add Class" to create a class derived from CDialog for your window. For learning purposes create a "dialog based" MFC program to learn how to make a dialog work.

Comment: So Add Resource file, make the window i want and then create a derived class, right? I'm still not sure about how i'm going to get the same theme for the window though...
But ty very much for the answer. I'm going to look into "dialog based" MFC

Comment: Hey Scott. I've been doing what you suggested but i came to realize that the window that i create will be outside the program, it will be a Windows window without the style of the parent program. Am i right?

Comment: I suggested you create a dialog based program to learn about MFC dialogs. Now you can do the same thing in a DLL project so your dialog will be "inside" the parent program. Whether it inherits the style of the parent program depends on how that style is implemented.